# Trying to restore a Linux 4.4 tablet system. adb commands fail and with error /syst/bin/sh: mkshrc [8]I'd not found

Tags: linux

I'm trying to restore a Linux 4.4 tablet system. Seems that all `adb` commands I have tried fail and give error `/syst/bin/sh: mkshrc [8]I'd not found` when viewing `/system/bin`, all files and dir, or listed as `unlink()`,and read-only.

Can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

try to check whether device is being detected or not.

`adb devices -l`

It seems issue with shell and might need clean flash